# Conditionally add methods to _.chain() in lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

In this example for instance, is there a way to conditionally add the `.upperCase()` method in this chain?

```js
const isUpperCase = true;

const users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1 }
];
 
const youngest = _.chain(users)
  .sortBy('age')
  .map(function(o) {
    return o.user + ' is ' + o.age;
  })
  .head()
  // Only add this method if isUpperCase above is set to true
  .upperCase()
  .value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three approaches when using chaining:

### Conditionally append to the chain

You have to save the partial chain then conditionally call the needed method on it *and save the output*. Then you can continue processing as normal:

```js
const isUpperCase = true;

const users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1 }
];
 
let chain = _.chain(users)
  .sortBy('age')
  .map(function(o) {
    return o.user + ' is ' + o.age;
  })
  .head();

// Only add this method if isUpperCase above is set to true
if (isUpperCase) {
  chain = chain.upperCase();
}

const youngest = chain.value();

console.log(youngest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### Add a manual step using [`.thru()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#thru)

The `.thru()` method will pass the values of the chain through a custom function and return the result. This allows you to apply conditional processing inside the custom function.

```js
const isUpperCase = true;

const users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1 }
];
 
const youngest = _.chain(users)
  .sortBy('age')
  .map(function(o) {
    return o.user + ' is ' + o.age;
  })
  .head()
  .thru(function(o) {
    if (isUpperCase)
      return _.upperCase(o);
    return o;    
  })
  .value();

console.log(youngest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### Conditionally process the result of the chain

This is probably easier, since you do not need to tamper with the chain itself. Based on the condition, you can apply `upperCase` after you have the value.

```js
const isUpperCase = true;

const users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1 }
];
 
const result = _.chain(users)
  .sortBy('age')
  .map(function(o) {
    return o.user + ' is ' + o.age;
  })
  .head()
  .value();

let youngest = result;

// Only add this method if isUpperCase above is set to true
if  (isUpperCase){
  youngest = _.upperCase(result);
}

console.log(youngest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### Use functional composition with [`flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/#flow)

There is an alternative approach by using [functional composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) to set up the processing chain. Then you can add or alter parts of this easily and then finally execute it against any dataset. The [Lodash FP](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) distribution offers readily made functions that are very well suited to this task. All functions are curried and the data parameter is moved to be last.

```js
const { flow, sortBy, map, head, upperCase } = _;
const isUpperCase = true;

const users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1 }
];

const chain = [
  sortBy('age'),
  map(function(o) {
    return o.user + ' is ' + o.age;
  }),
  head
];

// Only add this method if isUpperCase above is set to true
if (isUpperCase) {
  chain.push(upperCase);
}

const youngest = flow(...chain)(users)
console.log(youngest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```